# How to manage multiple div in one line with horizontal scrollbar

Tags: php, jquery

I want to display 30 same div. So I am taking for loop with showing 30 div. Now I want div in only one line. If the div is out of screen then it will show horizontal scroll bar.

The code is:

```
<div id="sort-able" >
     <?php for($j=0;$j<30;$j++){?>
         <div class = "dragg-able" >Home - <?php echo $j;?></div> 
                    
      <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: `style="display: inline;"`

Comment: did you put that on the inner div?

Comment: Please look my answer, it works for sure ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="sort-able" style="width: 100%; overflow-x: scroll; white-space:nowrap;" >
     <?php for($j=0;$j<30;$j++){?>
         <div class = "dragg-able" style="display:inline; ">Home - <?php echo $j;?></div> 
      <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Example: http://kelostrada.pl/test.php

Comment: You wanted a scroll bar to show up so it does, you need to explain better what you want to achieve

Comment: I am creating drag and sortable function of j-query. so I will move div one to another place. ex.- In these 30 div, I will drag div 1 to div 5 or other place.  So I want to show 30 div in one line with horizontal scroll. All is done but 1 thing is remaining. that is - showing 30 div in one line with horizontal scroll.

Comment: well my code shows 30 divs in one line with horizontal scroll. Look at the example